Conditional probability for 3 random variables failing
I'm sure I'm doing a wrong assumption here but I can't see it and was hoping someone would point it out.
Suppose three continuous random variables $x_t, x_{t-1}$ and $x_0$.
We can write the conditional probability $q(x_{t-1} | x_t, x_0)$ as:
$$
q(x_{t-1} | x_t, x_0) = \frac{q(x_{t-1}, x_t | x_0)}{q(x_t|x_0)}
$$
Now, if I marginalize $x_0$ on the l.h.s., I get:
$$
q(x_{t-1}|x_t) = \int dx_0 q(x_{t-1}|x_t,x_0) q(x_0)
$$
Similarly, I can marginalize $x_0$ on the conditional joint pdf, $q(x_{t},x_{t-1}|x_0)$, as well as in the single body pdf, $q(x_t|x_0)$, namely:
$$
q(x_{t},x_{t-1}) = \int dx_0 q(x_{t},x_{t-1}|x_0) q(x_0) 
$$
$$
q(x_{t}) = \int dx_0 q(x_{t}|x_0) q(x_0) 
$$
Now, I can write down the conditional probability again, $q(x_{t-1}|x_t) = q(x_t,x_{t-1})/q(x_t)$, which would imply the following equality:
$$
\int dx_0 \frac{q(x_{t-1}, x_t | x_0)}{q(x_t|x_0)} q(x_0) = \frac{\int dx_0 q(x_{t},x_{t-1}|x_0) q(x_0) }{\int dx_0 q(x_{t}|x_0) q(x_0) }
$$
which on particular cases does hold, i.e., $q(x_0)=\delta(x_0 - x_{0i})$, but one can see that for $q(x_0)=1/N \sum_i \delta(x_0 - x_{0i})$ the previous equality breaks and, in general, that equality breaks.
So I'd like to understand where's the implicit assumptions which does not hold here.
Thanks!


Now, if I marginalize $x_0$ on the l.h.s., I get:
$$
q(x_{t-1}|x_t) = \int dx_0 q(x_{t-1}|x_t,x_0) q(x_0)
$$

No. Applying the Law of Total Probability under the condition of $x_t$ gives:
$$q(x_{t-1}\mid x_t)= \int \mathrm d x_0~q(x_{t-1}\mid x_t, x_0)~q(x_0\mid x_t)$$
